# Can't draw figures with Qiskit in Visual Studio

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm using Qiskit in Visual Studio 2019. I want to draw quantum circuits, but it only shows their sizes with text instead of figures. The output on the interactive window is like this.

```
>>> from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: %matplotlib inline

In [2]: qr = QuantumRegister(1)
   ...: cr = ClassicalRegister(1)
   ...: circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)
   ...: circuit.h(qr[0])
Out [2]: <qiskit.extensions.standard.h.HGate at 0x2c9b16b8e80>

In [3]: circuit.draw(output="mpl")
Out [3]: <Figure size 240.8x138.46 with 1 Axes>
```

Is there any way to draw circuits correctly, or is it simply that Qiskit doesn't work in Visual Studio?

---

<edited> the qiskit version

```
In [6]: print(qiskit.__version__)
0.8.1
```

Comment: For me it works in the separate terminal in visual studio (on wsl) not in the interactive window. Do you know the version?
print(qiskit.__version__)

Answer (score 3):

qc.draw can output the figure to matplotlib. Simply call plt.show() at the end.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)
qc.draw(output="mpl")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the interactive window, it probably works similarly to Jupyter Notebooks. I would run `%matplotlib inline`, and then try calling `circuit.draw(output='mpl')` again.

You could also try running the line `circuit.draw(output='mpl')` twice, as that also will render the `Figure` in Jupyter Notebookes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Is that running```# import anything I need<br/>    # define the circuit<br/>    %matplotlib inline<br/>    circuit.draw(output='mpl')``` and ```# import anything I need<br/>    # define the circuit<br/>    circuit.draw(output='mpl')<br/>    circuit.draw(output='mpl')```? Neither work for me.

Comment: How do I start a new line btw? It looks awful without any.

Comment: My answer is assuming that the interactive window in Visual Studios works similar to coding in Jupyter Notebooks. Example code of what I meant is:
`%matplotlib inline`
`import qiskit`  
`from qiskit import QuantumCircuit`  
`qc = QuantumCircuit(5, 5)`
`qc.draw(output='mpl')`

This is the most basic example without any gates, but it should still render the empty circuit `Figure`

Comment: Also not sure about starting new lines. Each of those code blocks is a separate line though.

Comment: Still not working. But I found I can draw figures in Jupyter Notebooks, so it might be better using Jupyter Notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `interactive` :

```
qubit.draw(output='mpl', fold=50, interactive= True)
```